# Prove that $\sqrt[n]n>\sqrt[n+1]{n+1}$ for all $n \geq 3$

Tags: inequality, radicals

Can someone please prove the following?

$$\sqrt[n]n>\sqrt[n+1]{n+1} \quad \text{for all } n\geq 3.$$

I have tried lots of different approaches but none of them has worked. I tried  induction and also tried to modify the expression but nothing worked.

Comment: Pretty easy to do by induction, describe what you tried

Comment: I have started  with regular induction base case, step case  and so on but i just cant find a way to make use of the induction hypothesis

Comment: What is your induction hypothesis (you'll do well on this site if you put "__what have I tried__" (two underscores, title, two underscores, an underscore is a _) (this is a title in your post) then describe your effort, even if it's wrong.

Comment: See also [Which of the numbers $1, 2^{1/2}, 3^{1/3}, 4^{1/4}, 5^{1/5}, 6^{1/6} , 7^{1/7}$ is largest, and how to find out without calculator?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1331015) and [other posts linked there](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/1331015).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:** Remember that $n \geq 3$. $$\sqrt[n]{n} > \sqrt[n+1]{n+1}\Leftrightarrow n^{n+1} > (n+1)^n$$

One more step,

$$n > (1+\frac{1}{n})^n$$

Comment: i tried that  way to it didnt work.

Comment: @Bakyr Did you get it?

Comment: to be honest no. i dont get how you get to this step

Comment: As $n\geq 3$ you may divide by $n^{n}$ on both sides of the inequality. Once you have done that, notice that $(1 + \frac{1}{n})^n < 3 ,\forall n$. Remember that $\lim_{n\to\infty} (1 + \frac{1}{n})^n = e < 3$.Then the proof is done.

Comment: now i get it. thank you , but i am not only interested for the inequality to hold at infinity, i want it to hold for every n>=3

Comment: You are welcome @Bakyr.

Answer (score 0):

This can be proved by calculus. Let $y = \sqrt[x]{x} = x^{1/x}$. Then $\displaystyle\ln y = \frac{\ln x}{x}$, so that
$$
\frac{1}{y} y' = \frac{1-\ln x}{x^2} \implies y' = x^{1/2} \cdot \frac{1-\ln x}{x^2} = \frac{1-\ln x}{x^{3/2}}.
$$
Since $1-\ln x < 0$ for all $x \geq 3$, we have $y'<0$ on $[3,\infty)$, that is, $y$ is a  decreasing function on $[3,\infty)$.

Comment: what does that y' mean

Comment: $y'$ is the derivative of $y$ with respect to $x$, that is, $\displaystyle\frac{dy}{dx}$.