# Compare two below natural numbers: $2016^{2017} < 2017^{2016}$

Tags: calculus, inequality, arithmetic, exponential-function, exponentiation

Help me Compare the two following natural numbers below
$$2016^{2017} < 2017^{2016}?$$

Many thanks.

Comment: Have you tried it yourself? Where are the arguments that should answer the question?

Comment: I tried but I can't.

Comment: Please, explain what you tried and tell where you are stuck. It would be difficult to help you not knowing. Cheers and, by the way, welcome to this fantastic site. It is a very interesting problem.

Comment: I don't know which number is greater than?

Comment: Let me give you a hint: You can try to prove an equivalent inequality $(1+1/2016)^{2016}<2016$, and try to estimate an upper bound for $(1+1/n)^n$ for $n\in\mathbb N_+$.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Our criterion is sometimes harsher when the problem seems more elementary. Those posts about moderner mathematics (such as functional analysis or algebraic geometry) without explaining attempts aren't that downvote- or closing-attractive.

Comment: You are asking about inequality of the form $n^{n+1}<(n+1)^n$, which is equivalent to $\sqrt[n]n<\sqrt[n+1]{n+1}$. You can find several posts about this on this site. I have mentioned some of them in [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1331015#1333558). Or you can try searching in approach0 for the [first inequality](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24n%5E%7Bn%2B1%7D%3C(n%2B1)%5En%24&p=1) or the [second inequality](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24%5Csqrt%5Bn%5Dn%3C%5Csqrt%5Bn%2B1%5D%7Bn%2B1%7D%24&p=1) or for another equivalent form.

Comment: Do you want how to do the comparison or just the answer?

Comment: Also related: [Fastest way to check if $x^y > y^x$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/517555) (and other posts [linked there](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/517555).)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Taking logarithms of both sides we get:
$$
2016^{2017} > 2017^{2016}\Leftrightarrow 2017\ln 2016>2016\ln 2017 \Leftrightarrow \\ {} \\ \Leftrightarrow \frac{\ln 2016}{2016}>\frac{\ln 2017}{2017}
$$
The last relation is true because the function $f(x)=\frac{\ln x}{x}$ is (why ?) strictly decreasing for $x>e$.

Comment: @KonKan. So I think 2016^2017 > 2017^2016. Thanks.

Comment: @Bích Hải Triều Sinh, you are welcome.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know whether it's right or wrong but I still try as hard as possible.

We make a fraction for the two numbers. So we have:
$$\frac{2016^{2017}}{2017^{2016}}=\frac{2016.2016.2016...}{2017.2017.2017...}=2016(1-\frac{1}{2017})(1-\frac{1}{2017})...=\frac{2016}{e}>1$$. In a nutshell, we have $$2016^{2017}>2017^{2016}$$

Moreover, we easily see that if 0 < x <= 2, then the numerator is less than  the denominator.

Answer (score 2):

*Hint:* The function $x \mapsto x^{1/x}$ has a single critical point at $x=e$ and is decreasing for $x \gt e$.